# XSLT Code for how to delay message

Tags: xslt

I have a requirement in one of my project says that splitting message into multiple messages and sending down to third party system.(i have implements but it will happen at the same time)

But my concern is we need to maintain some delay(Ex:50secs) in between message to message while sending down.

So how to maintain the delay by using xslt code. Any answer which could help me?

Comment: How is the XSLT which splits the messages apart passing it on to the third party system?

Comment: xslt is just a transform of one xml file into another (or possibly several others). It doesn't do any processing with the resulting files.  So you can't do this with xslt itself, but you might be able to do it with whatever is invoking the xslt transform

Comment: You could investigate whether your XSLT processor supports Extension Functions, and write an Extension Function which implements the delay -- but I agree with Paul that this would be the wrong way to approach the problem, and you should fix this in the messaging/protocol layer, not the transformation layer.